# Change values in a list of vectors according to a key

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors as following:-

```
a <- list(c("10002", "10003", "10004"), c("10001", "10005"),
          c("10001", "10004"), c("10003", "10005"), c("10002", "10003"))
```

And I have a data.frame which is as following:-

```
b <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                col2=c("10001", "10002", "10003", "10004", "10005"))
```

So basically I want to replace the character values of in list `a` by the corresponding numeric values in `col1` of `b` . So that my list will become:-

```
c <- list(c(2, 3, 4), c(1, 5), c(1, 4), c(3, 5), c(2, 3))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
lapply(a, function(x) b$col1[match(x, b$col2)])
```

Alternative: since I found out, after posting my answer, that my answer is identical to Ronak's

```r
lapply(a, function(x) ifelse(x %in% b$col2, b$col1, NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `unlist` `a` values, `match` with `col2` and get the corresponding `col1` values. Finally we use `relist` to maintain the same structure as `a`.

```
relist(b$col1[match(unlist(a), b$col2)], a)

#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 4

#[[4]]
#[1] 3 5

#[[5]]
#[1] 2 3
```

You can also use `lapply` with `match`.

```
lapply(a, function(x) b$col1[match(x, b$col2)])
```